# Prevent transformerless powerless supply going full voltage on O/P in case of open circuit

Tags: power-supply, transformerless

I would like to automate two of my lights using Nodemcu and a 5 V relay board. I am planning to power the relay and Nodemcu with a transformerless power supply. Is there a way to prevent full voltage across O/P in case of open circuit. i am on a 240 V AC 50 Hz system.

Comment: Yeah.  Don't use a power supply that is just waiting for a chance to kill you.

Comment: What is "O/P" ? Output ? Please don't use confusing acronyms.

Comment: It's hard to say without knowing the minimum current required to give an acceptable voltage.

Comment: transformerless (capacitive) supplies are usually low current - probably won't run your relay. Need to start from the current requirement to see if it works.

Comment: Draw a schematic please.

Comment: @HenryCrun  I am sure i can get away with running a 5v relay on 3V DC on 0 load but not sure  of what will happen with load.

Comment: You miss the point - relays require significant current. Capacitive transformerless supplies provide limited current. 5V relays require much more current than higher voltage relays - which is why transformerless appliances often use 24 or 48V relays. You need to start from your current requirement to specify the power supply type - not the other way around.

Comment: Right your correct. Max amp i can get from a transformerless supply in 800mA @230 V.

Answer (score 2):

This is too vague to be capable of being answered properly. The supply is mains powered? If it is *really* transformerless (i.e. there is no galvanic isolation between mains and the output), none of its outputs belong anywhere near any conductor that has any possibility of ever being touched by a human. Full stop. You certainly should not ever consider trying to prevent this by using zeners or whatever. If the thing ever fails and the zener gets connected to the mains, the mains will win. Every time.

That said, that does not mean that transformerless supplies cannot be used for lighting. They can and are -  but the lighting is always designed to stay heavily insulated, even if it gets wet.

Basically, you probably shouldn't be thinking of doing this if you need to ask this question.

Comment: It would be tucked away in a gang box indoors and left undisturbed.It's better to ask than kill myself trying.

Comment: OK, but you also have to be concerned about where the lights are and how well they (and all cables leading to them) are insulated - presumably not tucked away in a box. ;-) Indeed, the only stupid  question is the one that noone bothered to ask.

Answer (score 0):

The way to prevent a dangerous high voltage is to prevent an open circuit. Add a zener diode that is permanently connected across the output and will limit the voltage to a safe level. Choose a zener voltage that is a bit higher than the normal output voltage, but not so high that your circuits will be damaged if they are briefly connected to that voltage...maybe 5.1V in this case. Be sure to select a zener that can pass the maximum current from your supply when no other load is connected.

That said, you are dealing with very dangerous circuits. If you are not sure that what you are doing is safe, don't do it. Make sure that no one can possibly make contact with **any** of the signals from your circuit at any time.